# Using Azure Key Vault RSA Key to encrypt and decrypt strings

Tags: c#, .net, azure, encryption, rsa

I have setup Azure Key Vault to retrieve RSA Keys for encryption. Azure send me an object of type KeyBundle. This object contains a JsonWebKey of type **RSA of size 2048**. Looking at my RSA Key, it has 2 methods called `Encrypt(byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding)` and `Decrypt(byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding)`. Now I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a simple string like this:

```
public EncryptionManager(KeyBundle encryptionKey)
{
    string test = "Hello World!";
    var key = encryptionKey.Key.ToRSA();
    var encryptedString = key.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test), RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
    var decryptedString = key.Decrypt(encryptedString, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
}
```

Encryption works, but decryption throws an exception with message:

> Key does not exist.

Here is the StackTrace

> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(SafeNCryptKeyHandle
>   key, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, AsymmetricPaddingMode paddingMode, Void*
>   paddingInfo, Boolean encrypt)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(Byte[]
>   data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding, Boolean encrypt)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.Decrypt(Byte[]
>   data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding)    at
>   NxtUtils.Security.EncryptionManager..ctor(KeyBundle encryptionKey) in
>   C:\Repos\Enigma\EnigmaPrototype\SharedLibaries\NxtUtils\Security\EncryptionManager.cs:line
>   26

I am really not familiar with cryptographic algorithms. My question is: How can I encrypt and decrypt a simple strig using this RSA Key provided by Azure?

Thanks!

Comment: "but decryption throws an exception."  I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, what I did is here although I searched from internet  and got this from the Microsoft docs

so this is my working code below

```
public static class KeyVaultEncryptorDecryptor
{
    public static string KeyDecryptText(this string textToDecrypt , KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient, string keyidentifier)
    {
        var kv = keyVaultClient;
        try
        {
            var key = kv.GetKeyAsync(keyidentifier).Result;
            var publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(key.Key.N);
            using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            var p = new RSAParameters() {
                Modulus = key.Key.N, Exponent = key.Key.E
            };
            rsa.ImportParameters(p);
            var encryptedTextNew = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);
            var decryptedData = kv.DecryptAsync(key.KeyIdentifier.Identifier.ToString(), JsonWebKeyEncryptionAlgorithm.RSAOAEP, encryptedTextNew).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var decryptedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedData.Result);
            return decryptedText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return default;
        }
    }

    public static string KeyEncryptText(this string textToEncrypt , KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient, string keyidentifier)
    {
        var kv = keyVaultClient;
        try
        {
            var key = kv.GetKeyAsync(keyidentifier).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(key.Key.N);
            using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            var p = new RSAParameters() {
                Modulus = key.Key.N, Exponent = key.Key.E
            };
            rsa.ImportParameters(p);
            var byteData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
            var encryptedText = rsa.Encrypt(byteData, true);
            string encText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedText);
            return encText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return default;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ToRSA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.webkey.jsonwebkey.torsa?view=azure-dotnet) has a default boolean parameter indicating if the private key should be available, or not.

Since you didn't explicitly say `true` it is implicitly `false`, therefore your key object is public-only.  With a public RSA key you can encrypt data or verify a signature, but you cannot sign or decrypt.